# Table thead background overflow with border radius on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a border radius on my th element.
Also, i set a background for specific columns in my table.

```
 <colgroup>
    <col span="2" style="background-color:red">
    <col style="background-color:yellow">
  </colgroup
```

on Chrome it's working good. issue on firefox, it ignores my border-radius and there is overflow of the background color.
Note that i can't set the background for each tr individually because it's a gradient color and it'll repeat itself.
Here is a short fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/n645szk7/

Render it once on chrome and again on Firefox to see the differences.
Thanks.

Comment: The border radius is on your ```th``` but the background applied to your column, add them together.

Comment: I do understand that, but first how it's working on Chrome? second, i can't. as i said i must to apply the bg once and since it's gradient i can't apply it specifically to the th/tr .

Answer (score 0):

### Test Both attributes

- `-moz-outline-radius: 25px;`
- `-moz-border-radius: 25px;`